# What should I look for when searching a new calisthenics/gym routine?

Tags: workout-routines, gym, calisthenics, gymnastics

I am looking for a new calisthenics routine. I do enjoy working with just my body weight, but I feel like I need to step it up a noch.

to give you a feel of my level:

- 1 set of 50 pushups.
- 10 clean chin-ups (maybe a little bit more if I struggle)
- about 6-7 pull-ups
- l-sit hold 45 seconds
- run 1-1.5 hour
- leg raises 10+

I have 1.5 hour to spend in the gym and I am looking for a full body workout. 
I am also happy to use weights. 
I don't use protein shakes. jus some vegan protein bars.

My program at the moment include: 
Day 1, 2 and 3:

3 sets:

10 chinups

50 sec wall sit

30 reversed dips (18kg)

30 squats (18kg raised above head when going up)

20 push ups

10 pull-ups (I fail at this on my third set can do maybe 4 and then I'll have to stop and do two more etc)

10 hanging leg raises

10 upside down shoulder press

Abs:

30 crunches

30 bicycle c.

30 toe touches

20 reversed abs

15 side plank hip lifts right

30 crunches

15 side plank hip lifts left

40 russian twists

30 bicycle crunches

15 oblique v-ups right

20 reversed crunches

15 oblique v-ups left

20 leg raises

Plus 30 minutes running

On my fourth day I usually do some technicals (hand stands or typewriter pull-ups or head banger pull ups) and 1 hour jogging @ 11 km/h

In my days off I try to do 100 push-ups (2 sets of 50)

Comment: https://thenx.com Seems like a ton of good stuff online for this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixmxOlcrlUc
But I would probably keep the workouts to around an hour myself, but I'm using weights not calisthenics right now.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at Bodyweight resources like Overcoming gravity and Paul Wade/Al Kavadlo Books

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get better at calisthenics you seem to be on the right track. Things like push-ups, pull-ups and L-sits are very good basics to get the strength required for more advanced moves you'll learn later down the road.

**The next step I would suggest you to focus on are handstands and muscle-ups.** And here's why: To do more advanced calisthenics moves like front lever, back lever, plance, one arm handstand, you're going to need a lot of core and upperbody strength.

Progressing from pull-ups to muscle-ups requires you to improve your explosive power with high pull-ups and explosive pull-ups. This will give you a lot of upperbody power which you'll need later for the other movements.

Learning a handstand requires a lot of power in the shoulders and core. Most of your balance during a handstand comes from engaging your core, learning how to do tihs will benefit you later on when you start trying to to static holds.

Both of these exercises also require good grip strength in your hands which is also important for the more advanced movements.

If you want to know ways to learn how to do a handstand for example let me know, I can share some exercises to get started.